# No exact matches in call to instance method 'append', macOS swift with Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, macos, google-cloud-firestore

I´m new in apple development and I´m trying to populate NSTableView with struct from Firebase Firestore.

But I get an error in appending the data:

```swift
Var customerArray: [CustomerData]()

func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return customerArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSTableCellView?{

    let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: tableColumn!.identifier, owner: self)as? NSTableCellView {
        let customer = customerArray[row]
        cell.textField?.stringValue = customer.fullName
        return cell
    }
    return nil

}
```

This is the method that I make the call to firebase and it works.

```swift
func loadCustomers(){
    db.collection(self.collectionName).addSnapshotListener { (QuerySnapshot, error) in
        self.customerArray = []
        if let error = error{
            print("Error getting documents,\(error)")
        } else {
            for document in QuerySnapshot!.documents{
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())"). // here the data printed in console
                let data = document.data()
                if let customerName = data["fullName"] as? String, let customerNumber =
                    data["phoneNum"] as? String {
                    let newCustomer = Customers(id: document.documentID,fullName: customerName, phoneNum: customerNumber, email: "", address: "", profession: "", age: "", dateOfBirth: "")

                    self.customerArray.append(newCustomer) // Here I need Help with appending data to NSTableView

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[Here is a Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Re7Z.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are not declaring the array correctly

```swift
var customerArray = [CustomerData]() 
// or
var customerArray: [CustomerData] = []
```

Second thing is that your "customerArray" seems to be declared as `[CustomerData]` and you are trying to append `Customers` object to it. If these types are not related at all the compiler will get confused and it is probably the reason for this error. You might want to change the type of `customerArray` to the following:

```swift
var customerArray = [Customers]()
```

Here are some resources for learning how to style your Swift code:

- [The Official raywenderlich.com Swift Style Guide.](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide)
- [Swift Style Guide by Google](https://google.github.io/swift/)

But to learn more on how to use Swift most efficiently I would **strongly** suggest to take a look a the official [Swift Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) and preferably reading the whole thing. It's incredibly informative!